# Trouble with phone number in ipad mini

Tags: ios, swift, int, phone-number

I am developing an app that shows a 10 digit number. When I run it in my iPhone 6 it shows ok. It displays `8183874201`. But when I run it in my old iPad Mini it show the number in a format like this `-467821389`.
The code I am running is:

```
var telefonoCasaStaff = self.timelineData[0].objectForKey("TelCasa") as Int
self.telCasaTextLabel.text = String(telefonoCasaStaff)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int` is a 64-bit integer on 64-bit devices, and a 32-bit integer
on 32-bit devices.

`8183874201 = 0x1E7CC0299` exceeds the range of 32-bit integers, and
apparently is truncated to 32-bit.

You could use `Int64`, but generally, storing phone numbers
as integers makes not much sense, and you should use strings instead.